What happens if you do an Invite challenge after getting the character from a Wish?
Lucked out and a Wish got me Collei, but the Curtain of Leaves event is still in my Events section where the reward is inviting Collei.
What do I get now, if I complete its task of clearing Floor 4, Chamber 3 of the Spiral Abyss? A Collei Stella Fortuna? Or is it a useless Event for me now, if I only care about characters and not the Spiral Abyss?

In this scenario you will get a Stella Fortuna.
Unless otherwise noticed collecting a character from an event, a wish, an in-game mail, the shop or any other source is treated as the same.
Therefore collecting a copy of Collei from the Curtain of Leaves will have the same effect as if you got her from wishing on a banner:

you will get a Stella Fortuna and 2 Masterless Stardust if your character has not reached C6 yet.
you will get 5 Masterless Stardust otherwise

